# How to determine sysprep status

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, sysprep

I have a requirement to be able to determine how far Windows is through a sysprep sequence.  After running sysprep /generalize we are creating an image of the OS which is then being used to create other VMs.  When the created VM starts up, sysprep runs the specialize step and then the VM reboots.  At this point the new VM is good to go.

The problem I am facing is that I have a sensitive application that should not run until after the specialize step has been performed and the machine rebooted (I have the source for the application so can make changes to make this happen).

The question is how can I determine that the OS is in this state.  Are there some sysprep registry keys that can be read to determine how far through the process things are?  Is is possible to tell when all the sysprep stuff is complete?

Answer (score 3):

Look for `setupact.log` and `setuperr.log` files under the following paths:

- C:\Windows\Panther
- C:\Windows\Panther\UnattendGC
- C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\Panther

Comment: my setupact file is 3796 line!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your application to not start on boot during image creation, then use config management like Salt or Puppet (or just a script) to set it to start on boot after a machine is fully deployed.